# Random Spaces in PHP message

Tags: html, css, email

I am using the following PHP code to send e-mail when the users submits a form.

```
$to = 'mail@example.com';
$subject = 'Thank you for your mail ' . $mailRefrence . ' - www.example.com';
$headers = "From: " . 'info@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

$message = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'> <html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'> <head> <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;.......";
$message .= $mailReference;

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Please note that the HTML-code inside the $message-variable is much longer, I've just removed it due to it is way to long to be pasted here. The source code is available here: http://zurb.com/playground/projects/responsive-email-templates/basic.html

However, when the mail is sent to the user, there is random spaces in the text. Sometimes the spaces appear in the text, and sometimes in the code which often ruins the whole design of the mail.

Does anyone have an idea why this happens and how to solve it?

Comment: can you show us the source code of two different mails that arrived in your mailbox?  Make sure to remove any personal details if you don't want to share them.

Comment: Tangentially related, but you do validate and sanitize data from the user before stuffing it into the e-mail and using the parameters to send mail, right?

Comment: Yes, I do. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: Second time I will ask (and the last time), you have a correct source code in the page you show us in your link, yet a failed code arrives in your mailbox. Can we please see the code of an arrived mail to locate the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use `trim`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

this will remove white space

Comment: I'm sorry but this won't help.